# What is Python Ishell command to show the variables and dataframes that have been loaded?

Tags: python, pandas, shell

I'm trying to see the variables and dataframes that are already loaded. I'm learning on datacamp. They have an online IDE which is quite simple but it doesn't show the variables that have been loaded. I'm wondering if there is any IShell command to show those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this magic command:

```py
%whos
```

This is what an output would look like:

```py
Variable   Type         Data/Info
---------------------------------
StringIO   type         <class '_io.StringIO'>
TESTDATA   StringIO     <_io.StringIO object at 0x7f6f8e81c550>
df         DataFrame        1   2   3   4   5\na <...>z5\nd  j1  j2  j3  j4  j5
np         module       <module 'numpy' from '/us<...>kages/numpy/__init__.py'>
pd         module       <module 'pandas' from '/u<...>ages/pandas/__init__.py'>
plt        module       <module 'matplotlib.pyplo<...>es/matplotlib/pyplot.py'>
sns        module       <module 'seaborn' from '/<...>ges/seaborn/__init__.py'>
sys        module       <module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Tested on `datacamp` in both `jupyter notebook` and their own IDE.